# Comatose (rails plugin) javascript error on Class.create()

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm using comatose version 2.0.5 with my rails 2.2.2 app.  It's using the standard comatose admin layout, which loads its own javascript libraries.

it's blowing up on this line:

```
Layout.LiquidBase = Class.create();
```

saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: Class is not defined`.  This is in chrome.

My javascript knowledge is patchy and i don't know if this is maybe due to chrome using a later version of javascript or something?  Or expecting Prototype to be loaded? Any ideas anyone?

thanks, max

Answer (score 0):

It was prototype related:  i fixed this by including prototype.js.

Sorry to answer my own question, but thought it better to leave it here for the record rather than delete it.